# How can I execute a method by accessing autowired object in spring MVC from separate standalone java application

Tags: spring-mvc, cron, scheduling, executable-jar

Let's we have a class in webapp.war (spring MVC 4.2.2.RELEASE)

```
public class SomeClass{
      @Autowired
       private MyInterface implObject;

       public void method1(){
            implObject.doSomething();
           // statements ...
        }
}
```

and another class in standalone.jar

```
public class MainClass{
   public static void main(String[] args){
       // want to create object of SomeClass
      // or execute doSomething() ...
   }
}
```

*Note: application will be deployed in clustered environment, standalone.jar will be executed by shell script (it will be registered in crontab).*

I want to schedule some **job** (fetch records and send to weblogic queue JMS ...), using Unix crontab. and don't want to repeat DB operation separately (in standalone.jar).

Please also suggest if I can make standalone.jar small in size.

Quartz or similar implementation is not expected in my case.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by extracting necessary part of webapp.war, into app.jar.

Scheduling and batch configured using crontab.

Used maven build tool i.e maven-shade.

Any required configuration left to spring.